# Facing Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`. when running jest testcase in react-native (expo)

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, react-test-renderer

Below is the code for error:  `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'source' supplied to 'Image'.`

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
 return (
  <Image source={require('app/assets/image.png')}/>
 );
}
```

I've defined `name` config in package.json as `app`

I'm receiving this error when I'm running a jest test.

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide relative path to the photo, something like:

```
  <Image source={require('../../assets/image.png')}/>
```

(Depends on the file location)

Comment: Tried that, doesn't seem to work...... Just to be clear, the jest testcase breaks, not the ui